# Image Slightly Off Center

Tags: html

**Hi,**
This image is slightly off center but it's imperative it's dead on as it's the bottom of a box and it looks really weird with it sticking out.
[This is what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiads.png)

If you could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using CSS-only for borders ?
You can achieve the same effect by applying a class to your block-element :

```
<style type="text/css">
.rounded {
    border:solid 2px #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
```

Then apply your style :

```
<div class="rounded"> 
   .... 
   <input type="submit" ... />
</div>
```